# How to detect external urls using Javascript

Tags: javascript, external-url

My objective is simple, I'm kind of surprised that i can't find an answer to this in other posts, i apologize in advance if i missed it....

I have a textarea input. I want to make sure users don't post links to external sites.

I prefer to do this client side and simply prevent submission if external link is present.

I have seen numerous posts on how to find urls and make them into href's. I suppose i can use  the same logic to simply remove them, but that will not prevent the users from proceeding, what i want to do is specifically stop them for submitting if external links are present.

I also need to allow for links within the same domain, so the actual url of detected links must be compared as well. I've seen ways to do this once i have the url in a string on its own, but right now, it is somwhere in the middle of a parapraph of text.

Comment: Client side validation is for the convenience of the end user, server side validation is where you enforce your rules. You *cannot* trust the data coming from the client browser. I can tamper with the form submit data any number of ways *after* your client side javascript has decided it's OK. You **must** also do server side validation.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this client side only. You must check server side too. Client side checks are only for improving the user experience. Any business logic MUST be handled on he server side.

It is trivial to do this as post or get:

`http://url.com?textareainput=http://urltoverybadsite`

You can make it nicer for your users by doing a quick regex:

```
<script>
function checkLinks()
{
   var links = document.getElementById('textareainput').value.match("/http:\/\//")
   if (!links)
   {
       window.alert("Links not allowed!")
       return false;

   }
   return true;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="checkLinks()"><textarea id='textareainput'></textarea></form>
```

Comment: Don't tell him NOT to do it client-side. Of course he should do it client-side, but IN ADDITION TO server-side.

Comment: @mblase75 that is what i meant. I added "ONLY" to the end of my first sentence to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    var noExternalURLs = true;
    var currentDomain = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
    var links = new Array();
    var re = new RegExp('^'+currentDomain,"gi");

    // Get protocol & domain of URLs in text
    links = document.getElementById('mytextbox').value.match(/(https?:\/\/[\w\d.-]+)/gi);

    // Loop over links. If protocol & domain in URL doesn't match current protocol & domain then flag
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++)
    {
        if( links[i].match(re) == null )
        {
            noExternalURLs = false;
        }
    }

    return noExternalURLs;  // prevent submit if noExternalURLs==false
}
</script>

<form id="myform" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <textarea id="mytextbox"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for the suggestion, i'm going with this option. I appreciate @byron-whitlock suggesting a very simple way to do this although it does not seem to check against the current domain name as doe sthis solution. I'm running into some issues which i think have to do with the fact that I'm using TinyMCE, hopefully I can debug it so it works properly. Thanks again.